# Why JAXB is not marshalling my own subclass

Tags: jaxb, marshalling

I have a jaxb object which can be marshalled successfully, and it has a list object, then I make a new object like below

```
public class Sub extends SuperJAXBClass{

@Override
public List getList1(){
//override here
return ...;
}
}
```

Then the code like below:
SuperJAXBClass sjc=new Sub();
marshall(sjc)

Then I found the List1 in Sub is not marshalled successfully.
Any one knows why this happens? 
How to solve it?

Comment: How are you creating your JAXBConext?  The following may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/Inheritance

Comment: JAXBContext.newInstance(SuperJAXBClass.class);

Answer (score 4):

You could do one of the following:

**Option #1 - `@XmlSeeAlso` Annotation**

JAXB (JSR-222) implementations can not use Java reflection to determine all the possible suclasses.  As a work around you can annotate the super class with the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation that provides JAXB a reference to the subclasses.

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Sub.class})
public class SuperJAXBClass {
}
```

**Option #2 - Pass the Subclass When Creating JAXBContext**

If you include the subclass when creating the `JAXBContext` then JAXB implementations will be aware of it.  When a subclass is passed in metadata for the super classes is also created.

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Sub.class);
```

Comment: After debug, I found the sub class has a getList1 method whil it has a hidden getList1 method, which i think it's super class' method. and may be that's why each time when JAXB marshall the sub class, the hidden getList1 method returned is empty, so it can't be marshalled.